# Prove that for each $1 \leq p<\infty$ the set $\ell^p$ is a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

We fix a real number $p \in[1, \infty)$. The $p$-norm of a scalar sequence $x=\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is
$$
\|x\|_p:=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_n\right|^p\right)^{1 / p} \in[0, \infty]
$$
and $x=\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is called $p$-summable if $\|x\|_p<\infty$. We let
$$
\ell^p=\ell^p(\mathbb{N}):=\left\{\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mid x_n \in \mathbb{K} \text { for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \text { and } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_n\right|^p<\infty\right\}
$$
be the set of all $p$-summable scalar sequences.

I would like to prove that for each $1 \leq p<\infty$ the set $\ell^p$ is a vector space. Here below you can find my approach: what do you think?

We need to show that it satisfies the following properties:

1. Closure under vector addition: For any two elements $x$ and $y$ in $\ell^p$, their sum $x + y$ should also be in $\ell^p$.
2. Closure under scalar multiplication: For any element $x$ in $\ell^p$ and any scalar $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ (where $\mathbb{K}$ is the underlying field, either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), the product $\alpha x$ should also be in $\ell^p$.
3. The existence of a zero element: There should be an element in $\ell^p$ such that adding it to any other element in $\ell^p$ leaves the latter unchanged (identity element under vector addition).
4. Additive inverse: For every element $x$ in $\ell^p$, there should be another element $y$ in $\ell^p$ such that $x + y$ is the zero element (existence of additive inverses).

Let's go through each property step by step:

1. **Closure under vector addition**:
   Let $x = (x_n)$ and $y = (y_n)$ be two elements in $\ell^p$. Since both $x$ and $y$ belong to $\ell^p$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^p < \infty$. Now, consider the sequence $z = (z_n)$, where $z_n = x_n + y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $x_n$ and $y_n$ are in $\mathbb{K}$ (either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), their sum $z_n$ is also in $\mathbb{K}$.

Now, we need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |z_n|^p < \infty$. By the triangle inequality, we have:

$$
|z_n| = |x_n + y_n| \leq |x_n| + |y_n|
$$

Using this inequality, we can estimate:

$$
|z_n|^p \leq (|x_n| + |y_n|)^p \leq 2^p (|x_n|^p + |y_n|^p)
$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^p < \infty$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (|x_n|^p + |y_n|^p)$ converges. Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |z_n|^p$ converges as well.

Thus, $z$ is in $\ell^p$, and $\ell^p$ is closed under vector addition.

2. **Closure under scalar multiplication**:
   Let $x = (x_n)$ be an element in $\ell^p$, and let $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ be a scalar. We need to show that $\alpha x$ is also in $\ell^p$. Consider the sequence $y = (\alpha x_n)$. Since $x_n$ is in $\mathbb{K}$, the product $\alpha x_n$ is also in $\mathbb{K}$.

Now, we need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^p = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\alpha x_n|^p < \infty$. Since $\alpha$ is a scalar, we can factor it out of the sum:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\alpha x_n|^p = |\alpha|^p \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p
$$

Since $x$ is in $\ell^p$, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty$. As long as $\alpha$ is finite (which it is since $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$), $|\alpha|^p$ is also finite. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\alpha x_n|^p < \infty$, and $\alpha x$ is in $\ell^p$.

3. **Existence of a zero element**:
   Consider the sequence $0 = (0, 0, 0, \ldots)$, where all elements are zero. Clearly, $0$ is in $\ell^p$ since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |0|^p = 0 < \infty$.
4. **Additive inverse**:
   For any element $x = (x_n)$ in $\ell^p$, consider the sequence $y = (-x_n)$. Since each $x_n$ is in $\mathbb{K}$, the negation $-x_n$ is also in $\mathbb{K}$.

Now, we need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^p = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |-x_n|^p = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty$. Since $x$ is in $\ell^p$, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty$. Therefore, $y$ is in $\ell^p$, and it serves as the additive inverse of $x$.

Since $\ell^p$ satisfies all the properties of a vector space, it is indeed a vector space for each $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Comment: “ Using this inequality, we can estimate:” how can you get the second inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got all of the right ideas down.

If I had to nitpick, I would say that you didn't show that $(0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ($0$ being the identity in the underlying field $\mathbb{K}$) is *actually* the zero element. It's certainly obvious, I daresay a one-liner, but if one wants to be thorough (e.g. to appease a professor grading one's homework), you may as well prove it. All you've shown is that $(0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^p$.

(That is, you need to show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} + (0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for every $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^p$.)

Likewise, the additive inverse of a sequence is indeed obvious, but you should ensure that you prove it: that is, prove that $(-x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ really is the additive inverse to $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, by showing their sum is $(0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. (All you've shown is that $(-x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^p$.)

Of course, maybe you're working in a context where these details can be assumed to be sufficiently obvious, but something about the nature of your writing feels like you're dealing with a lower-level class where such details can't be taken for granted, hence my commentary.